# Node app on Heroku and libreoffce buildpack . Error converting file: Error: Could not find soffice binary

Tags: node.js, heroku, libreoffice, buildpack, soffice

I am using libreoffice convert to get a pdf from a doc file.
locally with libreoffice software installed, everything is working perfectly.

On heroku, after deploying and using buildpacks specifically:
heroku-buildpack-libreoffice-for-heroku-18

I am receiving the following error :
Error converting file: Error: Could not find soffice binary

heroku run soffice --version
returns the version but I still get the error.

I cd into my build and soffice is installed.

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.